# Create A Depression in an object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, photoshop-effects

I want to create this [effect](http://cdn2.digitalartsonline.co.uk/cmsdata/slideshow/3514287/step_5.jpg) (the second one)

[image]

using the first one as a source, ultimately to create the last one. I'm trying to learn some stuff, following a tutorial but the guy is using a tool that's no longer in Photoshop (he's using CS 3). Is there any other way I can do this?

His original instructions.

> Open smooth sphere.jpg (the first sphere). In the Liquify filter (Cmd/Ctrl + Shift + X), make small circles with the Mirror tool (M) over the centre to create a depression. Press OK. Erase part of this, leaving a bevel, and darken the whole in Curves (Cmd/Ctrl + M). Copy Mountain.jpg into this image and create a clipping mask with it over the shape.

Thanks!

Comment: Tell it that nobody likes it :)

Comment: Which tool no longer exists?

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter lol. If only it were that easy.

Comment: @MG_ The mirror tool in the liquify tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just take a look at the picture, its too easy to do it without any tool. Here's how I do it.

1. You need to have a sphere to start with
2. Contract your selection & make a new sphere that's half the size of the original.
3. Fill it with white color in a new layer
4. Make a selection of this new layer, CTRL+click & go to Select, Modify->Expand
5. Make it like 10
6. Fill this with dark gray color inside a separate layer (you can create a highlight using the dodge tool)
7. Place this layer below the white sphere
8. Using the similar steps, select the white sphere you created in step 3, & make a sphere bigger then it
9. Place this sphere below the gray border sphere
10. Fill it with white color, use Filter-> Gaussian blur & adjust opacity of the layer

**Update:**

To add your background image do this,

11. Select your main sphere, blue sphere in this case (Ctrl + click to make a selection.
12. Make a new layer, drop your image in this layer.
13. Now press ctrl+shift+i (invert selection) to select everything except the sphere

    14. Press delete on your image layer
    15. Set the image layer to darken, or overlay and reduce its opacity.
    16. You may also use filter, distort-> spherize on your image first (to give it a spherical look)

Use this tutorial as a reference & apply the same technique to get your desired result [How to make your own planet in Photoshop](https://creativewhim.com/make-your-own-planet-in-photoshop/)

There you have it =)

[image: Sample]
[image: settings]

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks. I'm trying to improve my skills here and I loved how you did it. Cheers

Comment: One question though, this method doesn't exactly give the final result when I need to make the picture (mountains) a clipping mask.

Comment: @MartinPowletteJr I updated my answer, you may upvote my answer if you found it useful. If it solves your problem please mark it as an answer. Thank you !

Comment: @MartinPowletteJr Just a note, in my image the center sphere is white, it should always match the background color to give it as a hole in the middle. I just did it on a whim...